How to execute code after an event callback in ib_async / ib_insync
Trying to write a Python script that will keep a connection open, and when an option trade is made, grab the IV and greeks and write it to a spreadsheet.  This way I can track IV/Greeks when a trade is opened and when it is closed. Most of the code is working, except the event handling. It is choking on
ib.qualifyContracts(*contracts)
The error is
Exception in callback _SelectorSocketTransport._read_ready()
handle: <Handle _SelectorSocketTransport._read_ready()>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.12/lib/python3.12/asyncio/events.py", line 88, in _run
    self._context.run(self._callback,self._args)
RuntimeError: cannot enter context: <_contextvars.Context object at 0x11a0016c0> is already entered


The code is:
#!/usr/bin/env python
# coding: utf-8
import settings
from ib_async import *
util.patchAsyncio()

ib = IB()
connection = ib.connect(settings.host, settings.port, clientId=settings.master_client_id)

def options_trade(trade):
    print ("Getting option greeks and other data...")
    contracts = []
    contracts.append(trade.contract)
    print (contracts)
    ib.qualifyContracts(*contracts)
# rest of code to execute would go here

def on_exec_details(trade:Trade, fill:Fill):
    print ("Start execution details")

    print ("Order status: ", trade.orderStatus.status)
    print ("Fill execution price: ", fill.execution.price)
    print (trade.contract)
    print (trade.contract.secType)

    if (trade.contract.secType != 'OPT'):
        print ("Not an option contract, will not load greeks")
    else:
        # get greeks for this contract
        print ("This is an option contract, will load greeks and IV data and save to spreadsheet")
        print (trade.filledEvent)
        options_trade(trade)

    print ("End execution details")

ib.execDetailsEvent += on_exec_details
ib.run()

I've tried adding util.patchAsyncio() but still no go. Also not sure if ib.run() is they way to run this.

Use Async version of qualifyContracts and add async before function def. Minimal example as:
from ib_insync import *
util.startLoop()  # uncomment this line when in a notebook

ib = IB()
ib.connect('127.0.0.1', 4002, clientId=1)

contract = Forex('EURUSD')
ib.qualifyContracts(contract)

async def onBarUpdate(bars, hasNewBar):
    if hasNewBar:
        print(bars)
    else:
        print("No new bars")
    await ib.qualifyContractsAsync(contract)

bars = ib.reqHistoricalData(
    contract,
    endDateTime='',
    durationStr='1 D',
    barSizeSetting='1 hour',
    #whatToShow='TRADES',
    whatToShow='MIDPOINT',
    useRTH=False,
    keepUpToDate=True,
    formatDate=1)

print(util.df(bars))
#ib.barUpdateEvent += onBarUpdate
bars.updateEvent += onBarUpdate

import asyncio
async def dymmy():
    while True:
        await asyncio.sleep(1)
ib.run(dymmy()) #make it interruptable
#......
#after Ctrl-C
bars.updateEvent -= onBarUpdate

